# How exactly does this work string.split(/\?|\.|!/).size?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I know, or at least I think I know, what this does `(string.split(/\?|\.|!/).size);` splits the string at every ending punctuation into an array and then gets the size of the array.

The part I am confused with is `(/\?|\.|!/)`.

Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Escaped question mark or escaped dot or not escaped exclamation mark. Any of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a **Regular Expression**. That particular one matches any '?', '.' or '!' in the target string.

You can learn more about them here: http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are surrounded by slashes `/  /`

The backslash before the question mark and dot means use those characters literally (don't interpret them as special instructions)

The vertical pipes are "or"

So you have `/` then question mark `\?` then "or" `|` then period `\.` then "or" `|` then exclamation point `!` then `/` to end the expression.

`/\?|\.|!/`

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression splitting on the char "a" would look like this: `/a/`. A regular expression splitting on "a" or "b" is like this: `/a|b/`. So splitting on "?", "!" and "." would look like `/?|!|./` - but it does not. Unfortunately, "?", and "." have special meaning in regexps which we do not want in this case, so they must be escaped, using "\".

A way to avoid this is to use `Regexp.union("?","!",".")` which results in `/\?|!|\./`

Answer (score 1):

```
(/\?|\.|!/)
```

Working outside in:
 
The parentheses `()` captures everything enclosed.
The `//` tell Ruby you're using a Regular Expression.
`\?` Matches any `?`
`\.` Matches any `.`
`!`    Matches any `!`
The preceding `\` tells Ruby we want to find these specific characters in the string, rather than using them as special characters.

Special characters (that need to be escaped to be matched) are:

```
. | ( ) [ ] { } + \ ^ $ * ?.
```

There is a nice guide to Ruby RegEx at:
http://rubular.com/ & http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm

Comment: The regular expression does not contain parentheses and it's `\?`, not `/?`

Comment: Thanks, edited. As for the parentheses: OP expressed confusion in the whole expression so I didn't leave anything out.

Comment: Yes, but the regular expression is `/\?|\.|!/`, the parentheses belong to the `split` method. BTW, `\?` matches a single `?`, not one or more.

Comment: Confirmed & edited, thanks. Rubulars matched result box can be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

For SO answers that involve regular expressions, I often use the "extended" mode, which makes them self-documenting. This one would be:

```
r = /
    \? # match a question mark
    |  # or
    \. # match a period
    |  # or
    !  # match an explamation mark
    /x # extended mode

str = "Out, damn'd spot! out, I say!—One; two: why, then 'tis time to " +
      "do't.—Hell is murky.—Fie, my lord, fie, a soldier, and afeard?" 

str.split(r)
  #=> ["Out, damn'd spot",
  #    " out, I say",
  #    "—One; two: why, then 'tis time to do't",
  #    "—Hell is murky",
  #    "—Fie, my lord, fie, a soldier, and afeard"] 
str.split(r).size #=> 5
```

@steenslag mentioned [Regexp::union](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Regexp.html#method-c-union). You could also use [Regexp::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Regexp.html#method-c-new) to write (with single quotes):

```
r = Regexp.new('\?|\.|!')
  #=> /\?|\.|!/
```

but it really doesn't buy you anything here. You might find it useful in other situations, however.

Comment: `Regexp::union` handles the correct escaping, that is something.

Comment: @Stefan, I meant `Regexp::new` doesn't really help here. `union` is useful. I edited to clarify.

Comment: Oh, of course! I thought "it" would refer to `Regexp::union` :-)